# Detectar se pwa foi adicionado na área de trabalho

Tags: javascript, pwa

Estou desenvolvendo um site, usando os conceitos de PWA, para gerenciamento. Meu intuito é permitir que o usuário adicione-o a area de Trabalho.

A partir do momento que ele fizer isso, pretendo esconder uma div `<div class="div-resouces"> ... </div>` de minha págia. Minha **dúvida** é como identificar se meu aplicativo Web foi iniciado da tela inicial?

Aqui o manifest que vou usar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Se deseja detectar abertura por PWA poderia tentar esse código em javascript que tenta detectar se o site foi aberto em modo standalone.

```
function isRunningStandalone() {
    return (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches);
}
...
if (isRunningStandalone()) {
   /* código que sera executado se o site estiver em modo standalone */
}
```

Existem outras técnicas, verifique se consegue resolver o problema com o code que passei caso contrário dê uma olhada nesse material.

[PWA detect](https://gist.github.com/NekR/25420489ba5eea0364d0)

Além disso ainda existe uma página na documentação do google para tentar resolver o problema pode consutar aqui [Google PWA detect](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/display-mode)